# Java for loop type long not supported

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax-error, long-integer

I was trying to do some Project Euler question which involves pandigital numbers with special divisibility requirements of the first 5 prime numbers, and thought that this would be the starting point (see, 1023456789 is the first number being looked at, and 9876543210 is the last one).

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class pandigital_special 
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            for (long l = 1023456789; l <= 9876543210; l++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why the compiler claims that for loops only support integers? I have never heard of that. That is to say, the compiler says "The literal 9876543210 of type int is out of range".

Comment: Use 'L' after Number. it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine. The only problem is that your second number (9876543210) is out of the `int` range, but you are using an `int` literal.

To use a `long` literal, you can append an `L` to the end of the number:

```
9876543210L
```

Here is a more complete example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    for (long l = 1023456789L; l <= 9876543210L; l++){
      System.out.println(l);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop

```
for (long l = 1023456789; l <= 9876543210; l++)
```

you have number `9876543210` which is too large for int change it to

```
9876543210L
```

updated code will look like this

```
for (long l = 1023456789; l <= 9876543210L; l++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have an L after to declare it as a long, like this:

```
long l = 1023456789L
```