# max value of iterator in for loop in java

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop

Is long allowed inside of for loop in java? If yes, why does eclipse shows an error while putting a long value, If no, what is the maximum value that can be used inside a for loop as iterator?

Comment: where is the code ? what error?

Comment: Yes it is allowed.

Comment: Hard to tell without your code, but you may be running into this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999966/java-for-loop-type-long-not-supported

Comment: Thank you, it was very similar to this one only. I got my answer thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is allowed. This works just fine

```
for(long l=0;l<Long.MAX_VALUE;l++){
            System.out.println(l);
        }
```

Comment: Whilst correct, it seems unlikely that this will address OP's actual issue, unless you happen to have guessed exactly the code he is trying.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed, look:

```
for (long lng = 1L; lng < Long.MAX_VALUE; lng++)  {
    // your code
}
```

To see max `long` value that you can assign, you can use:

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Notice that I put `L` after literal `1` (it's `1L`) when assigning value to `long`, to avoid error when trying to assign  value exceeding `Integer` range (this error would occur when if you tried to assign value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to variable of type `long` without using long literal (this literal is upper- or lowercase 'L' character after digits, **without 'L' it's integer literal** and compiler checks that this number is currently out of `int` range).

When for `1` in my example this `L` was redundant, for numbers greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can only guess, but I assume you're trying to use a value that's too big to fit into an `int` literal where you want a `long`.

For example:

```
for(long x = 0; x < 9876543210; x++) {
    ...
}
```

This code will produce `The literal 9876543210 of type int is out of range` because although you defined `x` to be of type `long`, the *literal* you're using here is interpreted as `int` and is therefore too big.

To fix this, you need to explicitly tell the compiler, that you mean a `long` literal by appending a `l` or `L` to the value (upper-case `L` is preferred, because you can better tell it apart from a `1`):

```
for(long x = 0; x < 9876543210L; x++) {
    ...                       ^- notice the 'L'
}
```